# IEEEremainder print different output when I used code internally

Tags: java

```
public static double IEEEremainder(double f1, double f2) {
    return StrictMath.IEEEremainder(f1, f2); 
}
```

So `StrictMath.IEEEremainder(f1, f2)` is called from `Math.IEEEremainder` class.

I found `StrictMath.IEEEremainder(f1, f2)` from here http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html

And the code is, I used this code later:

```
public static double IEEEremainder(double x, double y) {
    // Purge off exception values.
    if (x == java.lang.Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || ! (x < java.lang.Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || y == 0 || y != y) return java.lang.Double.NaN;

    boolean negative = x < 0;
    x = Math.abs(x);
    y = Math.abs(y);
    if (x == y || x == 0) return 0 * x; // Get correct sign.

    // Achieve x < 2y, then take first shot at remainder.
    if (y < TWO_1023) x %= y + y;

    // Now adjust x to get correct precision.
    if (y < 4 / TWO_1023) {
      if (x + x > y) {
        x -= y;
        if (x + x >= y) x -= y;
      }
    }
    else {
      y *= 0.5;
      if (x > y) {
        x -= y;
        if (x >= y) x -= y;
      }
    }
    return negative ? -x : x;
  }
```

But the problem is when I execute the below code

```
  double d1 = 123.45 , d2 = 35.10;
  1. System.out.println(StrictMath.IEEEremainder(d1, d2)); // -16.950000000000003
  2. System.out.println(Math.IEEEremainder(d1, d2)); // -16.950000000000003
  3. System.out.println(IEEEremainder(d1, d2));   // 18.150000000000002
```

Third output is different from others two. For the third I used code the from http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html

What is the reason for different output where I used the same method?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp